# Zabbix - send a trap to a SNMP server

Tags: snmp, zabbix

How to generate a SNMP trap per event (custom media type script?) 
to a SNMP server/another monitoring tool ?

If so, how to pass the community + OID as arguments to the media type script?
By default, only the destination, subject and message seem to be passed to the script.

Comment: I've concoted a script which parses all the necessary parameters from a Zabbix Action (each line following a controlled structure), mapping all the required parameters from the zabbix notation to the SNMP tree values range and later calling snmptrap -v2c

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
snmptrap -v 1 -c public 127.0.0.1 '.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4' '0.0.0.0' 6 33 '55' .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4 s "eth0"
```

The **snmptrap** is linux command (so easy to use in shell scripting). It is contained in the `net-snmp-utils` package.

Answer (score 0):

**mib2zabbix**

Perl script will generate a Zabbix v3 Template in XML format from an OID tree in a SNMP MIB file.

Read more here:
https://github.com/cavaliercoder/mib2zabbix